# MySql not starting on Xampp : InnoDB plugin not initializing due to missing MLOG checkpoints

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

Unexpectedly MySql server not starting. I checked error logs and found two errors: Aria recovery failed and InnoDB plugin not initializing. Aria issue is solved but InnoDB not initializing.
The error logs-

```
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 26462238 between the checkpoint 26462238 and the end 26462208.
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-12-07 14:25:28 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Cannot find any solution on this.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109315/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb